# how do i put sdl texture objects in an object / how do i pass the renderer object?

Tags: textures, sdl

I'm new to c++, and SDL2. and I'm trying to make a program that has objects with SDL2 texture objects in them, while passing the SDL_renderer object around to the various objects to render them. my code for the main texture handler is as follows:

```
class mysurface {
    public:
    SDL_Rect pic;       // x/y where in the pic, and w/h how much of the pic.
    SDL_Rect loc;       // x/y where in the pic, and w/h how much of the pic.
    double angle = 0;
    SDL_Point center;
    std::string img = "";
    SDL_Surface *bmp;  // = SDL_LoadBMP(path.c_str());
    SDL_Texture *tex; //= SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(ren, bmp);
    mysurface(){}
    void update(SDL_Renderer *ren, std::string image, int x, int y, int w, int h){
        this->pic.x = 0;
        this->pic.y = 0;
        this->pic.w = w;
        this->pic.h = h;

        this->loc.x = x;
        this->loc.y = y;
        this->loc.w = w;
        this->loc.h = h;

        this->center.x = (int)(this->loc.x / 2);
        this->center.y = (int)(this->loc.y / 2);

        this->img = local() + image;
        this->bmp = SDL_LoadBMP(this->img.c_str());
        SDL_SetColorKey(this->bmp, SDL_TRUE, SDL_MapRGB(this->bmp->format, 0x0a, 0x0a, 0x0a));
        this->tex = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(ren, this->bmp);
    }
    void blit(SDL_Renderer *ren){
        //std::cout << "blitting";
        SDL_RenderCopyEx(ren, this->tex, &this->pic, &this->loc, this->angle, &this->center, SDL_FLIP_NONE);
    }
};
```

but,whenever i run the program, passing the renderer obj to it, it fails to render. is there a preferred way of doing this? am i being too pythonic?

Comment: Do you create renderer properly? Do you use `SDL_RenderPresent()` at the end of game loop (and `SDL_RenderClear()` before that respectively)? Also, you could use just simply structs, since you are not encapsulating anything.

Comment: the declaration looks like this: `SDL_Renderer* ren = SDL_CreateRenderer(win, -1, SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED | SDL_RENDERER_PRESENTVSYNC);` and is declared in `main()`. it is then passed throughout the program to different objects as a standalone variable. but whenever i pass it to an object's method, the thing needed to render, fails to show up.

Comment: You did not answered my second question. Do you use `SDL_RenderPresent` at the end of game loop? SDL is double buffered, which means, that every renderer has a buffer which is shown up on your screen and an another buffer which is in the memory and you can do whatever you want with it before you copy to the screen. `SDL_RenderCopy()` just copies your texture to the memorized buffer, but if you want to see the result on the screen, you need to call `SDL_RenderPresent()`. So, in fewer words, RenderCopy does NOT have any visible effect on screen.

Comment: Sorry about not answering your question, but yes, I do use `SDL_RenderCopy()` and then `SDL_RenderPresent()` but it dos'nt work while using my methods, only when the texture and all the peripherals for creating it and rendering it are in the same `main()` function.

Comment: You should try to get information about texture. After `SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface()`, check if tex == NULL, and if it is true, then print out the sdl's internal error function(`std::cout << SDL_GetError()`). If not this is the problem, then I can't help you, but there is great tutorial, where it is explained how to create a texture handler: http://lazyfoo.net/tutorials/SDL/10_color_keying/index.php . Also, you could post your code at Code Review SE, where they can optimize your code.